# Visual Studio Code "Could not install typings files for JavaScript ..."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to node.js and am trying to learn it with Visual Studio Code as my editor (1.13.1).

With my .js file open I see:

> Could not install typings files for JavaScript language features. Please ensure that NPM is installed or configure 'typescript.npm' in your user settings

I do have npm installed:

```
C:\>npm --help

Usage: npm <command>
```

How can I fix the message?

I could add 'typescript.npm' in my user settings but I don't know what value to give it. Please can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an [explanation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition) for your case. So it should be the full path of the `npm`.

In my case this is `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`.

Comment: I still see the warning even though I set: "typescript.npm": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm.cmd" (npm.cmd does exist there, and is also at "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm.cmd")

Comment: At the moment, I'm not getting the warning if I specify "typescript.npm": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin/npm.cmd".  Not sure why this is different to  "typescript.npm": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm.cmd".

Comment: @DavidA: Both `npm.cmd` scripts are completely the same. So I think it doesn't matter which one to use :)

Comment: Ah, I am completely new to this.  I installed npm through VS Code and the path is: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\npm.cmd"` but when I enter that, it says `Invalid escape character in string`;  I'll try installing node.js with the installer.

Comment: ah - in the settings you have to use double backslashes to escape the `\` characters.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is starting VS Code by administrator privilege.

Comment: The precondition is configure "typescript.npm" rightly.